# format.js with Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

So i have my destroy command. The problem is I don't want my users to be able to delete this category if it contains items. So I have an if statement in my destroy method. That works all great, but I'm using AJAX to have the page not load and using a destroy.js.erb file. My method is below:

```
def destroy
    @promotion_type = PromotionType.find(params[:id])

    if Promo.find_by_promotion_type_id(params[:id]).nil?
    @promotion_type.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to(promotion_types_url) }
      format.js  {render :layout => false }
      format.xml  { head :ok }
    end
    else
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js  {}
      end
    end
  end
```

This is my javascript(jquery):

```
$('a.delete').click (function(){
    if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
        var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
        $.post(this.href, {_method:'delete'}, null, "script");
        $(row).hide();
        return false;
    } else {
        //they clicked no.
        return false;
    }
```

One of my problems is that once they click yes, it hides the row and AJAX deletes its. If I didn't hide it, it would be deleted but since the page is doesn't refresh, it looks like it wasn't deleted, so I hide it for the effect. The only problem with this solution is when I get to my categories. I don't want users to delete it if it has items inside it. I can't throw ruby code in my javascript file, and I can't (or don't know of a way) to throw javascript variables or $(this) into a .js.erb file.

The code runs correctly for the most part, but it hides the row now even if it failed to delete it.  So i was going to throw an alert('Cannot be delete'); into my .js.erb file, but that alert fires regardless of whether it was or wasn't deleted.  I'm sure there's a better solution to do all this, but I don't know it.

Answer (score 2):

Like geowa4 says you can do the following

```
 $('a.delete').click (function(){
        if(confirm("Are you sure?")){
            var row = $(this).closest("tr").get(0);
            $.post(
               this.href, 
               {_method:'delete'}, 
               function(data){$(row).hide();}, 
               "script"
            );
            // Move from here to the callback
            //$(row).hide();
            return false;
        } else {
            //they clicked no.
            return false;
        }
 }
```

As an alternative you could simple have the JS "hide" code in your .js.erb file along with the alert. You will also need to pass a variable (@destroyed) to erb and then use an if statement for weather to fire the alert based on the @destroyed variable.

```
def destroy
    @promotion_type = PromotionType.find(params[:id])

    if Promo.find_by_promotion_type_id(params[:id]).nil?
      @deleted = true
      @promotion_type.destroy

      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to(promotion_types_url) }
        format.js  {render :layout => false }
        format.xml  { head :ok }
      end
    else
      @deleted = false
      respond_to do |format|
        format.js  {}
      end
    end
end
```

Comment: It works for the most part. But it is still hiding it even if it's not deleting it. I can't throw $(row).hide(); into the .js.erb file because row isn't defined. function(data)${$(row).hide();} is hiding the row regardless.  I'm not sure way (data) is there because it is never used.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just return true or false depending on whether it was deleted? Define a callback in your `$.post` to handle this.

```
$.post(yourURL, yourDATA, function(data){ myCallback(data); }, "text");

function myCallback(data) {
    if( data === "true" )
        ...
    else
        ...
}
```

I used "text" as a response format for demonstration. You might want something more like "json". The "script" format as you have will treat your response as javascript; since you said you copied that from somewhere, I don't think that' what you really need. IMO, what is returned should only be data, as you get with "xml", "text", or "json" formats. You can find more on the [jQuery docs page](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax).

Comment: Can you go more indepth? I got the .post code from another site and added the rest so I'm not sure how it works.